# How does ASP.NET get line numbers in it's generic error handler

Tags: asp.net, exception

Everyone is familiar with the default error handler for ASP.NET. The yellow boxes that contain Source Error (5 lines of code where the error happened) and Source File (filename and line number) like so:

```
Source Error:

Line 48:         public ActionResult TriggerException()
Line 49:         {
Line 50:            throw new SystemException("This is a generated exception to test the global error handler.");
Line 51:         }
Line 52:         


Source File: c:\MyApp\Controllers\TestToolsController.cs    Line: 50
```

I am building a custom error handler and want to get these same pieces of information, but they are not contained in the exception object. Does anyone know how I may retrieve these items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line number is not available in the Exception itself, but it is available in the StackTrace, like so:

```
try
{
    // code that throws an Exception here
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    var frame = new StackTrace(exc, true).GetFrame(0); // where the error originated
    var lineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
    // Handle line numbers etc. here
}
```

Comment: Great start. That gives me the filename and line number. How might I get the 5 lines of code?

Comment: You don't get the code. By having the file and line number, you or another developer can look up the problem. The original source code itself is never baked into the EXE/DLL.

Comment: So how does ASP.NET display the 5 lines in it's error screen on my production server when it only has my compiled application deployed?

Comment: Are you sure that is the case? Any error message showing source code on a production system is a huge security issue. It would appear that the source code is actually on the production system, either as code files or embedded in the PDB files (symbol files, which you would normally leave out on a production system. Are you deploying DEBUG builds with PDB files?

Comment: You are correct, the production server does not show the lines of code. My mistake. I never noticed the difference before. Thank you.