# How can I get the "Source Error" from a stack trace like Asp.Net does?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an asp.net application, and if there is an exception in the code I catch it log some details (the stack trace, exception details etc) to a database and return a reference code to the client.

I noticed that the ASP.Net yellow screen of death shows a few lines of code around the offending line as well as the stack trace.

[image: Asp.Net Yellow Screen of Death showing "Source Error"]

I want to log that "Source Error:" too. Where and how does the ASP.net get the "Source Error:" source code from?

Comment: Do not throw a new exception. Simply use 'throw' to preserve the source details.

Comment: @Hardrada, No, that's not what I'm asking. I've updated the screen shot to highlight the information I'd like to get hold of.

Comment: Just a side note, you have to be in debug mode to get the Source Error, which you don't want in a production system.

Comment: You won't be able to log any source if there is no PDB file. And, besides, the developer will be able to find the source, given the stack trace.

Comment: @mxmissile. Debugging Information, and "DEBUG" are different things. I agree that you don't want "DEBUG" enabled in production, but in my release builds (in production) I do include PDB debug symbols. I just tested this, and in RELEASE, I can still get the stack, line numbers and Source Error in the ASP.Net Yellow screen of death.

Comment: @John Saunders. Granted, you are right. But I still want to do it, if I can.

Comment: It looks like the code in the .NET framework responsible for getting source information is [`System.Web.FormatterWithFileInfo.GetSourceFileLines()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/ErrorFormatter.cs#37489503577dbd29).  Basically it does nothing more than open the source file, and find the line referenced by `lineNumber` in the error, along with 2 lines before and after.  It would probably be easier for a developer just to get the relevant version from your source control system and view it himself.

Comment: @mellamokb - +1. Wow that Microsoft referencesource site you linked to is awesome. I think you are right -if you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: This is also informative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586107/how-does-asp-net-get-line-numbers-in-its-generic-error-handler

Comment: @mellamokb. Thanks, they didn't get to the answer in that other question. So, line numbers come from PDB files. The source code, comes literally from the source code not the PDB. Nothing to do with DEBUG or not. In production you'd precompile your asp.net application which is why you don't have the source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** If you want the file name and line number of the error, you can get it this way:

```
var exc = Server.GetLastError();
var frame = new StackTrace(exc, true).GetFrame(0);

var sourceFile = frame.GetFileName();
var lineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

// sourceFile = c:\path\to\source\file.aspx
// lineNumber = 123
```

Reference: [How does ASP.NET get line numbers in it's generic error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586107/how-does-asp-net-get-line-numbers-in-its-generic-error-handler)

---

It looks like the code in the .NET framework responsible for getting source information is [**`System.Web.FormatterWithFileInfo.GetSourceFileLines()`**](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/ErrorFormatter.cs#37489503577dbd29).

```
...
for (int i=1; ; i++) {
    // Get the current line from the source file
    string sourceLine = reader.ReadLine();
    if (sourceLine == null)
        break;

    // If it's the error line, make it red
    if (i == lineNumber)
        sb.Append("<font color=red>");

    // Is it in the range we want to display
    if (i >= lineNumber-errorRange && i <= lineNumber+errorRange) {
        fFoundLine = true;
        String linestr = i.ToString("G", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        sb.Append(SR.GetString(SR.WithFile_Line_Num, linestr));
        if (linestr.Length < 3)
            sb.Append(' ', 3 - linestr.Length);
        sb.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(sourceLine));

        if (i != lineNumber+errorRange)
            sb.Append("\r\n");
    }

    if (i == lineNumber)
        sb.Append("</font>");

    if (i>lineNumber+errorRange)
        break;
}
...
```

Basically it does nothing more than open the source file, and find the line referenced by `lineNumber` in the error, along with 2 lines before and after.

Comment: Would you mind providing the values for `reader.ReadLine();` (Its just the stack code there, right?), `errorRange`, `lineNumber`, `fFoundLine` and `SR`? I would like to use this but those are the values I do not know where they are coming from.